# Implementing methods from other classes

Tags: java

I am not able to understand why is it not working?

I've got my methods class:

```
package particles;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;

public class Methods {
Graphics g;

public void showhud(){
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Screen: Game", 675, 10);
    g.drawString("Version: 1.0", 675, 25);
    }

}
```

But when i try to implement showhud() in my other class, it doesn't work!

This is how im using it:

```
package particles;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;
import particles.Methods;

public class Game extends BasicGameState {
Methods m;

public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException {

}

public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    m.showhud();
}

public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta) throws SlickException {

}

public int getID() {
    return 0;
}

}
```

The error i get is:

```
Tue Jan 01 17:19:36 NZDT 2013 ERROR:null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at particles.Game.render(Game.java:18)
at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.render(StateBasedGame.java:207)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:703)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:456)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:361)
at particles.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Comment: Where are you initializing `m` - `m.showhud();`? It appears to be null.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized `m` - it's (still) `null`, so when you execute

```
m.showhud();
```

you get a NPE because `m` is `null`.

You must assign an instance of `Methods` to the variable `m`

Comment: 'Methods m;' Is that not initialized?

Comment: @user1610541 - You need to instantiate `m` something like `Methods m=new Methods();` within the `render()` method or you need to supply a parameter of type `Methods` from your driver routine or the place where the `render()` method is invoked (after instantiating `m`) depending upon your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You never assign a reference to `g`.  In other words, you don't have a `g = ...` anywhere in your code.  As such, when your `Methods` class is instantiated, `g` is initialised to the default value, which is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

you havent initialised the `Methods m` object

by your code, i believe `int()` method should have initialised the `m object`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to instantiate both class members references, **g** and **m**. Currently, both references are pointing to nothing. They must point to Graphics and Methods objects respectively.

1. If possible, add a constructor to Methods class that will take care of initializing **g**.
2. If init() is the start of Game's (your class) lifecycle, then initialize **m** in this state/block.